# How can I implement a "pause" button for music in a Flash game?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I'm making a flash game, and I want to make a button. When I click on it, pause the music. When I click again, resume the music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
            private function stopMusic():void
        {
            _soundPosition = _soundChannel.position;
            _soundChannel.stop();
        }

        private function playMusic():void
        {
            _soundChannel = _sound.play( _soundPosition );
        }
```

When you stop, you save the current position, when you play, you play from the last saved position, if you set the _soundPosition propery to 0, the the play will do it from the beginning.